# Best way to create options in RPG

Tags: java

I am following a tutorial I found on youtube on creating a basic RPG with a GUI. The tutorial is very helpful in giving directions on how to handle panels and frames, but the way they handle user decisions seems very impractical. They have a switch case that uses the player's location, and then another switch case within that then handles the actions depending on what button the user enters. Im not saying that it doesn't get the job done, but it leads me to have a LONG switch case. I was wondering what would be the best approach to have a cleaner and more manageable code.

snippet of the code:

```
//depending on your position, you are given different action options
            switch(position) {
            //if you are in town, these are your options
            case "townGate":
                switch(yourOption) {
                //talk to the guard
                case "c1": talkGaurd(); break;
                //attack the guard
                case "c2": attackGuard(); break;
                }
                break;
            //if you are talking to the guard, these are your options
            case "talkingToGaurd":
                switch(yourOption) {
                //leave to the outside of the gate
                case "c1": townGate(); break;       
                }
                break;
            //if you are attacking the guard, these are your options
            case "attackingGuard":
                switch(yourOption) {
                //leave the the outside of the gate
                case "c1": townGate(); break;   
                }
                break;
            }
```

Comment: This is looking ripe for a combinatorial explosion. Instead of putting this into code, you put this into a data structure of some sort--think more how Choose Your Own Adventure books are assembled. In general, the key phrase applying to this sort of situation is "Replace Conditional with Polymorphism".

Comment: Yea, I'd probably separate places at least - into separate classes with common Interface and then manage them. That would also allow you to build and add locations as plugins to main game (Depending on the rest of implementation).

Comment: @chrylis Could you expand more on what you mean by using polymorphism to replace the cases?

Comment: As an example, you could have a `Location` object that says where you currently are, and an `Action` interface with a `do` method: `TalkAction`, `AttackAction`. Each `Location` has a `Map<String, Action>` that takes the place of your switch: `actions.get(yourOption).do(...)`.